# Alternative to PWD for a background script that uses current directory?

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm essentially trying to create a script in a Linux terminal for a text-based game that updates a file a certain way depending on your current directory as you `cd` around a series of files. The script works fine if I `source` it (or use . scriptName) in another directory, but I need it to run in the background upon the start of the game so that is continuously runs. This causes the working directory to default to that in which the script itself is in, regardless of which directory you `cd` to once it starts running.

Is there a way to make the script take the working directory that the player is in?

I've tried making a function outside of the script that changes a global variable to the directory, but it does the same thing because it's in the same one as the script. I believe the issue is using `pwd`, so I tried creating a function that takes the directory directly from the `PS1` variable, but I can't get the actual string from it.

This the piece of the script that takes the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $running="true" ]
#running is a variable from outside the script
do
location=$(pwd | gawk -F '/' '{ print $NF }')
#this takes the last directory listed in the result of $pwd
echo $location
sleep 7
done
```

(I apologize for any formatting issues, very new to stackoverflow)
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Thank you all, it works now!

Comment: You could have that script start a subshell that the user navigates in, grab its PID, then look at `readlink /proc/$thatpid/cwd` ...

Comment: As an aside, `[ $running="true" ]` will always be true. You need spaces on both sides of the equals sign to turn it into a comparison operator; your current code simply checks whether the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on AKX's idea with `cwd`. When you background the script the parent process id (`$PPID`) would be the users shell they are navigating in.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while sleep 3; do
  location=$(readlink /proc/$PPID/cwd | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
  echo Location: $location
done
```

Running above script in the background results in the current directory being printed every third second.